# How can I use github actions "amazon-ecr-login" and "build-push-action" together?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, amazon-iam, amazon-ecr

My goal is to build with `docker/build-push-action` action since it makes buildx and multiarch easy. I have a private ECR repo on AWS. I created an IAM user with the permissions below and put the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` in the github repository secrets. I tested with this locally (keys and account id redacted) and could push:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAexample
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=1234example
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

and docker push to my repo succeeds. This is the IAM policy attached to the role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:PutImage"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my actions yaml. When it gets to `docker/build-push-action` it builds the image, but fails to push with this error:

```
buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to push ***.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/nl-api-flask:9c878ca: unexpected status from HEAD request to https://***.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v2/nl-api-flask/manifests/sha256:1122bc7746fb861c9eeed48535c45600d0c2f317fd759232e29a8ed2efd60971: 403 Forbidden
```

Here is the yaml:

```
name: ci

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "setup-github-actions-build-test-and-push"

env:
  AWS_REGION: us-west-2
  ECR_REPOSITORY: nl-api-flask

jobs:
  docker:
    name: Build and test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

      - name: Set outputs
        id: vars
        run: echo "sha_short=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Build and push
        id: build-and-push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          context: .
          platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}/${{ env.ECR_REPOSITORY }}:${{ steps.vars.outputs.sha_short }}
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to add permission `ecr:BatchGetImage`, then it worked.

Since this is a multiarch build, at some point it tries to read (hence the HEAD request) from the repo. The permissions [from aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/image-push.html) do not assume you're doing this.

Comment: Oh my god. You save my day. How do you know this permission?

Comment: @KCC I read the error message carefully and noted that when it starts the push, it needs to get a manifest (the HEAD request) from the ECR repo. This is part of multiarch builds. That `ecr:BatchGetImage` permission seemed like the best candidate for that operation (getting an image and getting a manifest is *probably* the same type of operation), and it worked.